# How do I reset a table view?

Tags: xcode

I have a table view in an iPhone xcode tab bar application that shows data either alphabetically or numerically, depending on a user selected option in one of the tabs.  It works for the most part, but when I change the option and then go back into the table view, the table view initially looks like it did before the option was changed.  However, as new cells get scrolled into view, they have the new display mode.

I can identify when the option changes, but I can't seem to get the code correct that would re-initialize the cells such that the next time they come into view they have the correct values.  The data comes from a static array with set values, so I don't want to do anything with the data source, just the table view.

In other words, once the display option changes, I want to wipe out the table view I have so that the next time the table view displays it will show the correct data right from the start rather than after scrolling occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to call reloadData on the TableView.

[yourTableView reloadData];

Comment: This is how my view is declared, but when I try to do 

[tableView reloadData];

I get tableView undeclared.


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: As I think about it, I'm not sure reloadData will work for this, although I'm not familiar with it.  I am using a custom cell view to format 3 data items I am loading the table cell with.  I think that after my "options" tab has loaded and received input from the user, I want to release my table and start from scratch the next time it gets loaded.

Comment: I think you're trying to call it in the wrong place. It should be called somewhere that is causing the data to change, not in methods that are constructing the TableView.    If you have a tab bar and tapping one button changes the sort order, inside the action for that button you'd sort the data and then call [self.tableView reloadData]; using an iVar to your TableView.

*If you're changing something in another controller that affects the data in a TableView in a second controller, you need a delegate method back that will update the data and reload it. Or an observer. Many ways to do this.